# How can I share a directory with an another user?

Tags: permissions, shared-folders

I don't want the shared folder to be accessible by anyone on the system, I want it to be accessible just to a restricted set of users.

How to I do that?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Taken from this excellent post on [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2138476&p=12616640#post12616640) by Morbius1.

The classic Linux way of doing this sort of thing goes something like this:

1. Create the shared folder:

   ```
   sudo mkdir /home/Shared
   ```
2. Create the new user's group:

   ```
   sudo addgroup newgroup
   ```
3. Change ownership of the shared folder to the new group:

   ```
   sudo chown :newgroup /home/Shared
   ```
4. Add your desired users to that group:

   ```
   sudo adduser user1 newgroup
   ```

Repeat for all users.

Now you have some decisions to make about what you want those users to be able to do:

- **[a]** All group users can add to and delete from the folder and can read and but not write to each others files:

  ```
  sudo chmod 0770 /home/Shared
  ```
- **[b]** Same as above but only the owner of the file can delete it:

  ```
  sudo chmod 1770 /home/Shared
  ```
- **[c]** All group users can add to and delete from the folder and can read and write to each other's files:

  ```
  sudo chmod 2770 /home/Shared
  ```
- **[d]** Same as **[c]** except only the owner of the file can delete it:

  ```
  sudo chmod 3770 /home/Shared
  ```

A `1` in the first position of the chmod command is the *sticky bit* which prevents deletion of a file to anyone other than the owner.

A `2` in the first position of the chmod command is the *setgid bit* which forces all new or copied files to have the group of that folder.

A `3` in the first position of the chmod command is the combination of the sticky (`1`) & setgid (`+2`) bits.

There is one caveat to all this as far as the setgid bit is concerned. All new files created in and any files copied to that folder will in fact inherit the group of the folder. But not files moved to that folder. Moved files retain the ownership from wherever they were moved from. One way to get past this problem is to use bindfs.

Finally if you want others outside the group to be able to see the files but not change them change the final 0 in the `chmod` command to a 5 eg:

```
sudo chmod 0775 /home/Shared
```

Comment: Just curious, is normal create a `Shared` folder within the `/home` directory? or exists a better place to be shared among the users? - because at a first glance other user (a new one) can assume that `Shared` is simply other user

Comment: Depending on your system's `umask` value, you may have to do `setfacl -d -m g::rwx /home/Shared` to make sure new files and subdirectories have group write permission.

Comment: [b] The owner of the Shared directory can delete other files too. OS: fedora 36 workstation. umask 022

Comment: To take effect, the users must log off and log in again.

Comment: Why does **[a]** forbid writing to others' files? I thought having write permission on the directory allows one to write to the files in it?

Comment: as pointed out by @JoyfulPanda, users must log off and log in again, it should be mentioned in the answer since people (like me) might have a really frustrating and puzzling time following this (very correct, yet not complete to the fullest) answer and having things not working as expected.

Comment: This did not work as advertised when trying to share a folder on Ubuntu 22.04      
The resulting folder permissions were:    `drwxrwsr-x+  2 root    newgroup   4096 Mar 27 13:06 Shared`    To fix it, I had to give write permission to "other" so that it became:    `drwxrwsrwx+  2 root    newgroup   4096 Mar 27 13:06 Shared`    Why were the group permissions alone not sufficient in this case?

Thanks!