# Share files Using 12.04

Tags: filesystem

I'm new to Ubuntu. Just spent a couple of days overcoming all sorts of minor problems and performing tweaks and downloading apps etc.. Having installing 12.04 (32 bit) onto an old Xp machine leaving windows in a separate partition for optional booting.
Basically very impressed with everything. However have just hit a brick wall, ther does not sem to be a simple way of other users accessing each others files. Even the music files only seem to be available to the user that downloaded them. Surely Ubuntu does not require that each user has a complete duplicate copy of the music library. And how do two users have access to a commonly used file that they mutually update.
What am I missing....?

Comment: @Mitch: I read that he wants to share within Ubuntu.

Comment: By default Linux is more secure and keeps users files separate but you can create shared areas see this question [can't share a folder with a specific user](http://askubuntu.com/q/313089/107450)

Answer (score 0):

To answer part of your question, one thing that you could do is use the Ubuntu One cloud service and upload/sync files between multiple computers/users with that. I currently use it to sync my music library and documents between my desktop and laptop. I suppose it would work well enough for your purposes.

If you were desperate and wanted to just have a place where all users can put files to share with each other on one computer, you could use the Ubuntu installation disc to boot and create a new partition with g-parted, which would show up in Ubuntu as a completely different hard disc.