# How to create a directory for everybody?

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions

I have a lot of music that I want to share with and on all the accounts on my Ubuntu Linux box. I created one in `/usr/share/usrmusic` changed the user and groups to `userx:users` and the permissions to

`drwxrw-rw-    3 userx users  4096 Oct 26 12:20 usrmusic`

under a different user I can not get into the directory

It is now highlighted for whatever reason and then when I went into 
a different account to try and get to it it will not let me in saying I don't have permissions

```
usera@bw:/usr/share$ 
usera@bw:/usr/share$ cd usrmusic
bash: cd: usrmusic: Permission denied
usera@bw:/usr/share$
```

if I go `su` I can of course all permissions are set to drwxrw-rw- 312 userx users on everything in the directory and sub-directories

I added usera to the users group and still I cannot access it at all, and how do I get the directories to NOT be highlighted like it is now an executable directory  ?

it shouldn't be this hard!

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [can't share a folder with a specific user](http://askubuntu.com/q/313089/107450)

Answer (score 3):

Permissions are set to:

```
    drwxrw-rw- 3 userx users 4096 Oct 26 12:20 usrmusic
```

Where:

- **d** means directory
- **rwx** means that the owner (userx) has full access to the directory
- first **rw-** means that any other member of the group (users) can read from or write to the directory but cannot make it current directory using the *cd* command
- second **rw-** means that any other user can read from or write to the directory but cannot make it current directory using the *cd* command

To make the directory accessible ("executable") for others, you can try

```
    sudo chmod g+x usrmusic
```

for users group members, or

```
    sudo chmod go+x usrmusic
```

for anyone.