# Sharing a Network Drive through OpenSSH for a Specific Group

Tags: networking, server, permissions, ssh, samba

First question, hooray! To the point:

I'm not very well versed in Linux, I'm in the process of studying my Linux+.

I'm working on a variety of projects with friends, co-workers, and teachers. I'm currently the only person in all of these groups who has large storage space.

I've got SSH running on Port 40 (will be changed after I get everything working and configured).

Here's my problem:

How do I make group x's directory be on J:/ (Network Drive). Would this below work:

Create the shared folder:

```
 sudo mkdir /home/Shared
```

Create the new user's group:

```
 sudo addgroup newgroup
```

Change ownership of the shared folder to the new group:

```
 sudo chown :newgroup /home/Shared
```

Add your desired users to that group:

```
 sudo adduser user1 newgroup
```

[Source of Quote](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313089/how-can-i-share-a-directory-with-an-another-user)

instead of /home/Shared:

```
sudo chown :newgroup //192.168.1.112/j
```

Forgive the noobiness. I searched other topics but didn't find anything quite relevant. Most were just permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to do is this:

found on http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/how-to-mount-a-remote-folder-using-ssh-on-ubuntu/

> by Lowell Heddings :
>
> First we’ll install the module:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install sshfs
> ```
>
> Now we will use the modprobe command to load it
>
> ```
> sudo modprobe fuse
> ```
>
> We’ll need to set up some permissions in order to access the
>   utilities. Replace  with your username.
>
> ```
> sudo adduser <username> fuse
>
> sudo chown root:fuse /dev/fuse
>
> sudo chmod +x /dev/fusermount
> ```
>
> Since we’ve added ourselves to a user group, we need to logout and
>   back in at this point before we continue.
>
> Now we’ll create a directory to mount the remote folder in. I chose to
>   create it in my home directory and call it remoteserv.
>
> ```
> mkdir ~/remoteserv
> ```
>
> Now we have the command to actually mount it. You’ll be prompted to
>   save the server key and for your remote password.
>
> ```
> sshfs <username>@<ipaddress>:/remotepath ~/remoteserv
> ```
>
> Now you should be able to cd into the directory and start using it as
>   if it was local.

this is run from the client, not the server.

Comment: I followed that guide but when I do the final step, I get;
read: Connection reset by peer I've done a fair bit of Google Searching and none of the fixes have done it. What did I miss?

Comment: @BinaryData since you're running SSH on port 40, [@user761059](https://askubuntu.com/users/761059/user761059) (who can't yet comment) mentions that you need to include that port by instead running `sshfs -p 40 <username>@<ipaddress>:/remotepath ~/remoteserv`.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex Thank you for transferring it to a comment.